# How to catch input comma key event in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, angular10

I want to catch the event when a user presses comma (',') in an input.

I have tried this but it didn't work:

```html
<input (keyup.comma)="doSomething()" />
```

So how do you catch a comma inserted event?

I know I can catch using `(keyup)` only and check for the `keyCode`, but I would like to know if there is a way to do it in the way I described above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a way to make it work, Try this:

```
<input (keyup.,)="doSomething()">
```